# what is the dimension of the image of linear mapping $L(u,v,w)=(u-v,v-w,w-u)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

let $U,V,W$ be subspace of finite dimensional vectorspace P.
and define linear map $L$ like this.
$$L : U \times V \times W \rightarrow P^3$$
more specifically, $$L(u,v,w)=(u-v,v-w,w-u)$$

obviously, $$Im(L)=(U+V)\times (V+W)\times (W+U)$$

(when
$Im(L)=\{p\in P^3 : ~\exists$ $(u,v,w)$$\in U\times V\times W$  such that $L(u,v,w)=p\}$

$U+V=\{u+v : u\in U, v\in V\}$

$U\times V = \{(u,v) : u\in U, v\in V\}$)

so i thought following equation is true: $$\dim\text{Im}(L)= \dim(U+V)+\dim(V+W) +\dim(W+U)$$

simply using $dim(V\times W)=dim(V)+dim(W)$ two times.. however, it meets contradiction if i try to use the following relation.  $$dim(U \times V \times W)=dimkerL + dimImL$$

applying $dimkerL=dim(U\cap V  \cap W$), i get $$dim(U)+dim(V)+dim(W)-dim(U\cap V)-dim(V\cap W)-dim(W\cap U)+dim(U\cap V\cap W)=0$$
which doesn't make a sense at all.

i guess the problem is from dimension of the image. (thanks for your help)

Comment: I don't think your set-theoretic description of the image is correct (the "obviously" part). For instance, if $(x,y,z)\in L(U\times V\times W)$, then $x+y+z=0$.

Comment: i just edited what you said

Comment: @MrTanorus: you seem to have missed G. Sassatelli's point. all you have done in your edit is define the meaning of "image." that is not the point. the point is that you are wrong when you claim the image is the set $(U+V)\times(V+W)\times(U+W)$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli thank you for your answer!

Comment: @symplectomorphic thank you.

Comment: @MrTanorus More an observation than an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously $$\text{Im}(L) \subseteq (U+V)\times (V+W)\times (W+U)$$ holds, but not necessarily
$$\text{Im}(L)=(U+V)\times (V+W)\times (W+U)$$
e.g: $U=V=W=P$ then $\text{Im(L)} \ne P^3$, because $(0,0,1)$ not in $\text{Im}(L)$.

Comment: ahh..... i got what was the problem. can you give me an idea to get the dimension of the image?

Comment: oh, wait i got it. thank you for your help!